# UIButton won't work when UITextField is first responder

Tags: uiview, uibutton, uitextfield, first-responder

My ViewController's view contains:

- Custom UIView with UITextField;
- Custom UIView, which contains another custom UIViews (with UIButton) inside UIStackView .

So when UITextField is first responder - UIButton target (.touchUpInside) won't work. And it's all ok when UITextField is not first responder.

Comment: same problem - did you solve it?